# How to restart a file watcher robustly?

Tags: node.js, process, backup, restore, file-watcher

**I'm monitoring a large directory** of 500GB - 1TB with a file watching service that fills my database. During an **initial scan**, starting up the scanning and native watching events (add file, add directory), without even any postprocessing (metadata, thumbnails, database checks) **can take some 2-3 hours to complete**

When the watcher **restarts** (eg. crash or update) it has to **redo the initial scan**, during which I have two options:

1. **Full scan** - process everything again

   - The watcher would again look through all the file data and compare it with database entries.
   - If any found different or new, the database would be updated.
   - Speed : Very slow (~5-6 hours)
   - Lost data: None, most robust

.

2. **Oblivious scan** - ignore the initial scan's events

   - The watcher would initialise the watching correctly
   - but wouldn't be able to register any new files or changes between the beginning of restart and completion of the initial scan
   - Speed: Roughly a half time of the full scan (~2-3 hours)
   - Lost data: A lot, not really reliable (unless run at night when no changes can happen)

.

Furthermore, I considered a third option, but not really sure whether it's doable:

3. **Backup and restore**

   - During the run, use a second process to backup the watcher's data and any objects responsible for watching
   - On restart, instead of re-running the initial scan, restore the watching using the data stored in the backup process
   - Then continue working normally
   - Speed: Few seconds needed to restart the watcher process
   - Lost data: Probably none, unless data change happens exactly during the few seconds of restart (good enough for my case)

.

## **I'm wondering if you have ever tried the backup-restore of a watcher service? Or do you have any thoughts about it?**

.

(In my case the watcher uses node.js, [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar), [fs.watch](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener), [FSWatcher](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_fswatcher) and some [native C fs_event_wrap](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/fs_event_wrap.cc))